# A suggestion for an HTML/jQuery plugin to show horizontal trees (ala treeview)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree, treeview

I am working on a website where I want to use a horizontal tree. I have found a whole slew of treeviews plugins/controls that have the traditional vertical layout, but nothing for horizontal. I've attached an image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ6bA.gif) that roughly shows what I want. It doesn't have expand/collapse, interactive features, labels, etc, which I would like, but it gets the general idea across.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Erick

[image: Type of treeview I want]

Comment: +1 - This could be useful and I haven't seen a plugin like this. Probably wouldn't be too hard to write if nothing is available.

Comment: I'm confused, couldn't you just a make a horizontal list with CSS?  If it doesn't need to expand/collapse, or do anything specific, it sounds like you're just asking for a UI/navigation?  Like tabbed navigation?